# Inno Setup wizard is not responding while working with database

Tags: inno-setup

I create a database interactive installer by using Inno Setup. I am connecting to a database through wizard window as shown in the picture. When I press *Connect*, the installer window goes to not responding stage for few seconds (till the connection succeed/ or failed). Is their any way to make the wizard window responsive all the time?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in Inno Setup itself.

You would have to implement the connection in a separate DLL that would connect in a separate thread.

Comment: Yap, possible solution. I will do

Answer (score 1):

Do not perform long tasks in main GUI thread.

Create separate thread which performs long (or time consuming) tasks and communicates with GUI.

This is a little complicated but it is de facto standard in Windows programming.

Really nice example is downloading large files: there is special plug-in (http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=50) which does that in separate thread so GUI is not blocked.

Simply do the same - but do not download file but process your database actions.

Comment: I cannot find sources for this plug-in on the page I posted (I was 100% sure there were available). You can have inspiration in this my plugin: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ThreadTimer_plug-in or this one: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/BgWorker_plug-in